# Site not adjusting to smaller screen sizes as it should

Tags: html, css

I'd drop some code in here, but I think it would be best to just give you the URL. What's happening is the site was adjusting very well to various screen sizes, then I made some adjustments in the CSS and HTML, and now it isn't. I've spent the better part of today trying to figure it out. It's driving me mad.

Here's the link: http://lcc.outervenue.com

Have a look and tell me the idiotic thing I did to cause the problem.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "adjusting very well" and "now it isn't?" Not knowing what to look for specifically makes diagnosing the issue pretty difficult. Based on the CSS I found in the source, it's behaving as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry. Previously, I had max-width: 100%; set on the main container (#outermost), and the site would naturally scale down to fit 100% width on phones, etc. Now it is not working, and I cannot figure out why. The top menu is responsive as well.

Comment: in css have the width set to 100% width: 100%;

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After all that, I found the issue. Let this be a lesson in "sometimes it's the simplest thing".

There was a missing ";" in the CSS file. See below:

```
#menu {
    display: table-row
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: There are CSS validators out there that can check for this, you could use one in future to avoid this problem :)

Comment: Agreed. I did validate it, but used an html validator, so of course it didn't catch it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make the website responsive but is not familiar with this concept yet.

You can start improving your CSS by adding media queries such as:

```
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {
  #outermost{
    width:600px;
  }
}
```

This instructs the browser to resize the width of the div with the id #outermost to 600px when the browser window width is less or equal to 720px.

A suggested approach is to use a well defined responsive CSS framework such as Bootstrap to utilize a better grid system on the page.

Read more about Bootstrap grid here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I did try that, but it did not help. I'd be more than happy to change the framework, but have yet to find one that allows the middle div to fill the space between the header and footer, yet allow my header to be transparent so the background image of the page shows through. Using display: table; made that possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Menu is also not responsive.

You need to change the some CSS property for classes "#header" and "#menu". For both classes, try to replace "display: table-row" property with "display: block".

Comment: That did not work. If that were the problem, then the Events page would not scale. But it seems to be the only page that does. It's also the only page that does not have the big slider. Which would indicate that the big slider is the problem. However, I still can't figure it out. :o(

Answer (score 0):

in css have the width set to 100% 
`width: 100%;`